# Netbeans Garbled Text on Large Source Files - Fedora

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, fedora, netbeans-7

I was hoping someone could help me.  I have been trying to solve this problem where my large source files opened in NEtBeans ends up garbled unreadable text.  At first I thought it was netbeans but then it turns out being a Java issue.  I have followed these instructions (Screenshot on this page)

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSolvingEditorGarbledText

I am not sure I am entering the correct Device when I run the command lspci in terminal.

lspci gets me this

```
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Barts XT [ATI Radeon HD 6800 Series]
```

Which then I update my xorg.conf file with the following text.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "ATI Technologies Inc Barts XT [ATI Radeon HD 6800 Series]"
        Option          "AccelMethod"           "xaa"
        Option          "RenderAccel"           "true"
EndSection
```

But I still have garbled text when the source files become large.  When I say large I am talking about 2000+ lines.

Here is a screenshot

[image]

Comment: You've tried without bracket enclosed part? Maybe the right identifier is "ATI Technologies Inc Barts XT". Have you also try the second option (add property `-Dsun.java2d.pmoffscreen=false`)?

Comment: I wanted to try the second way.  but I couldn't find where that should go.  Is that just as a new option for that device.

Comment: +alain.janinm I just tried the "ATI Technologies Inc Barts XT" but that didn't work.

Comment: For using `-Dsun.java2d.pmoffscreen=false`, check this think http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html. Have you tried with an other "accelMethod"? Like EXA http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXA

Comment: ok I tried the pmoffscreen by adding to the end of the line in the netbeans/etc/netbeans.conf file.  No good.  I also tried the "EXA" with using the name "ATI Technologies Inc Barts XT" but that didn't work either.  Is there a way for me to see if that is the correct device name?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried with `ATI Radeon HD 6800 Series`? You also may run `update-pciids` in order to update PCI name http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-tell-which-graphics-vga-card-installed/

Comment: yeah none of these worked. It doesn't look like it's the java limit being exceeded.  I get the garbled text randomly on some small files, and large files.  This seems to be a bug with netbeans even if they haven't acknowledged it.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem worked it self out.  Could have been a bug in netbeans, and a older version of fedora.  I am not using 7.0.1 netbeans, and fedora 17.